# JS/JQUERY: Moving numbered table rows up and down without losing user input

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have created a table in HTML, consisting of table rows in a tbody tag.
I've used a javascript code snippet from mredkj.com to be able to add rows and delete them, too. The rows are sorted and their rank is in the first TD (cell) in every TR (row).

Now I would like the add the functionality of being able to manually 'resort' the tablerows.

The problems are:

- my javascript/jquery knowledge is
  very limited
- the ranks of tablerows
  do not get updated(when you delete a row, the
  rowranks get updated by the
  'reorderRows function, but calling this function from within my jQuery does not seem to
  sort out the problem)
- the user's input in textarea's gets erased as soon as up or down button is clicked.

For example: user adds a TR, that gets added at the bottom of the current list of tablerows, fills in the textarea and desides that the row (s)he filled should be ranked first, so she clicks the up arrow a couple of times, until it's on top.
The rank of the row is now #1 and the input is still in the textarea's.

My questions are:

- Does anyone know how I can make the
  rows update their ranking when the
  user moves the row?
- How do I maintain the user's input?

Any help is very much appreciated and if you have any other suggestions, please share them.

Code here: http://jsbin.com/eyefu5/edit - for some reason, the moving up and down doesn't work in js bin, it does however when I run it in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code to do what I think you were trying to do: http://jsbin.com/eyefu5/9/

My primary changes were to the following swap logic:

```
function swap(a, b){
  b.before(a);
  reorderRows(document.getElementById(TABLE_NAME), 0);
}

function getParent(cell){ return $(cell).parent('tr'); }

$('#diagnosetabel').on('click', '.upArrow', function(){
    var parent = getParent(this);
    var prev = parent.prev('tr');

    if(prev.length == 1){ swap(parent, prev); }
});

$('#diagnosetabel').on('click', '.downArrow', function(){
    var parent = getParent(this);
    var next = parent.next('tr');

    if(next.length == 1){ swap(next, parent); }
});
```

The biggest difference is that I switched the swap code to using jQuery's `before` method, which should take care of just about everything for you. I also added a call to the `reorderRows` method which you were already using. At the moment it starts at the beginning and reorders all the numbers after the swap, but you could narrow this down as needed because you know the only two rows which were modified.

Hope that helps!